# If amplitude (say voltage) of a 60Hz sine wave increases, doesn't rise time increase?

Tags: circuit-analysis

How does rise time relate to frequency? If I take 0-pi/4 of 2 60Hz sine waves, one being 2V and one being 10V, would the 10V have a higher frequency component because it has a steeper slope?

I hope his isn't one of those questions where you think about it and then delete it as quickly as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Risetime and slope are two different things.  A sinewave of higher amplitude will have a steeper slope, but the rise time will be the same as it takes the same amount of time to get from the lowest point to the highest point.  Also, a sinewave by definition has only one frequency component, regardless of its amplitude.  A sinewave is fully defined by a frequency, amplitude, and phase offset.

Waves which are not sinewaves can be thought of as a summation of a bunch of sinewaves.  For instance, a square wave contains all of the odd harmonics - 3, 5, 7, 9, etc. times the fundamental frequency.  The more of these harmonics are present, the flatter the tops and bottoms of the wave become, and the steeper the transitions become.  With a square wave, the sharper the edge, the more harmonics are required to represent it.  However, this has nothing to do with the amplitude - if you double the amplitude, you don't double the number of frequencies required, you just double the amplitude of all of the harmonics.

However: The slope of a sinewave does change as you increase the amplitude, and slope can sometimes be an issue!  Op amps generally have a specified output slew rate that limits the slope of the signal that it can reproduce.  It turns out that if you build an op amp circuit that has enough gain, you can run into the slew rate limit before the 3 dB bandwidth limit with a large enough signal.  When this happens, your nice sinewave will become a triangle wave at the output.  Naturally, this distortion will create more frequency components than the original signal.

Comment: @placeholder How so?  The time required to get from 0 to pi/4 does not change unless you change the frequency.

Comment: My bad, I misread the OP, and his conflating slope with rise time.

Answer (score 2):

> How does rise time relate to frequency?

In the case of a sinusoidal function of time

$$v(t) = A \sin (2\pi f \cdot t) $$

the *time* it takes for \$v(t)\$ to rise from \$0\$ to \$A\$ is simply \$\frac{T}{4}\$ where \$T\$ is the period

$$T = \frac{1}{f}$$

So, the rise time, in this sense, is independent of the amplitude.  Whether the amplitude is \$A = 1\mathrm{mV}\$ or \$A = 1\mathrm{kV}\$, the time it takes to rise from \$0\$ to \$A\$ is just

$$t_{0 \rightarrow A} = \frac{T}{4} = \frac{1}{4f}$$

Now, the *rate of change* is clearly proportional to \$A\$

$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = A \cdot 2\pi f \cos(2\pi f \cdot t)$$

but this doesn't imply that increasing the amplitude increases the frequency content.  By inspection, the frequency content of \$v(t)\$ is independent of \$A\$.

Answer (score 1):

A pure sine wave has only one frequency, no harmonics, no other frequency components.  The amplitude doesn't change that. The rate of change of \$A\cdot\sin(\omega t)\$ is

$$
A\,\dfrac{d\left(\sin(\omega t)\right)}{dt} = A\cdot w\cdot \cos(\omega t)
$$

where the maximum value occurs when \$\cos(\omega t) = 1\$, then \$A\cdot\omega\$ is the maximum slope, dependent on the amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

5Vpp 60Hz sine wave has the same frequency as the 10Vpp 60Hz sine wave.  The spike in the spectrum will be taller in the second case, but the spike will be at 60Hz still.

There are important practical parameters, which are related to the original question, though <sup>1</sup>.  These are [slew rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate) and [gain-bandwidth product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain%E2%80%93bandwidth_product).  A real OpAmp, for example, has a maximum slew rate and maximum GBW.

<sup>1</sup> You are not barking at a completely empty space.